# When (if ever) is the sum of two dependent geometric RVs negative binominal?

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, joint-distribution, convolution, geometric-distribution, sum

Imagine you have two random variables $X $ and $Y$, you know
$$
X \sim \text{Geometric}(p) \\
X + Y \sim \text{Negative Binomial}(2, p)
$$
I am interested in what if anything can be said about the distribution of $Y$ under these conditions. I now that a **possible** *solution* for Y that fits the above *system* is
$$
Y \sim \text{Geometric}(p)\\
Y \perp X 
$$
If no assumptions are made, it seems plausible that there might be infinite *solutions* for $Y$.

I am interested whether something more specific can be said in the case where $Y$ is required to have a geometric distribution given $X$ (parameter may depend on X). Is the trivial solution for that case (just assuming independence as above) the only solution in that case or are there others too?

EDIT:
For clarity, if all variables are supported on the non-negatives. (i.e. $X \geq 0, X+Y \geq 0, Y \geq 0$), then it can be shown (see comments below) that there is only one *solution* (namely the *independence solution*).

But in my particular use case, I have a slightly weirder scenario: $X$ is supported only on the positives, $Y$ is supported only on the positives if $X=1$ and on the non-negatives otherwise. (As a result **X + Y is always at least two**).

Comment: Are your $X$ and $Y$ distributed on the non-negative integers or on the positive integers?  Either way, I suspect you can show that in your final paragraph the conditional distribution of $Y \mid X=x$ is $\text{Geometric}(p)$ (i.e. independence) by considering the probabilities of small values for $X+Y$

Comment: thanks for your comment, I clarified in the question.

Comment: $X \geq 1, X+Y \geq 2, Y \geq 0$ is a little strange  if $X$ has a geometric distribution, and given $X=x$ you require $Y$ to have a geometric distribution. Ithink you need to choose between $X \geq 1, X+Y \geq 2, Y \geq 1$ and $X \geq 0, X+Y \geq 0, Y \geq 0$ for the supports

Comment: yes, I think you are right

Comment: it is only that in the particular problem I am facing, the "true domain" is actually what I had described initially, but it is a very weird problem. let's try figuring this simpler case out first, maybe I can adapt my problem to fit it.

Comment: I figured that with the universal non-negative support, there is only one unique solution, which is the independence solution. I found this using the filling-in method you described.

Comment: A funny coincidence since this week puzzle in our coffee room was to find the joint such that $X,Y$ are $U(0,1)$ and $X+Y$ is $U(1/2,3/2)$.